# ULTextField values disappears when the device orientation changes

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib, swift5

Im using Xibs to load cells inside a UITableViewController, and for some reason once the device orientation changes the cell is getting reloads and all the entered UITextField values get disappear. Is there a way to prevent this or better way to solve this problem of values getting disappeared.

my cell for row as follow

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = configCellView(index: indexPath.row) as? UITableViewCell

    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```

My configCellView method as follow

```
   private func configCellView(index: Int) -> UIView? {
    switch formType {
    //This LOG form works fine even device orientation changes 
    case .LOG:
        if let cell = getXibFile(cellType: LogFormTableViewCell.self, cellIdenifier: Constants.LOGFORM_CELL_IDENTIFIER) {
        
        return cell

        }

  //This is where the issue is 
    case .PROSPECT:
        switch index {
            case 0:
                let cell = getXibFile(cellType: LogFormTableViewCell.self, cellIdenifier: Constants.LOGFORM_CELL_IDENTIFIER)

                return cell
            default:
               
               
                    if let cell = getXibFile(cellType: ContactFormTableViewCell.self, cellIdenifier: Constants.CONTACTFORM_CELL_IDENTIFIER){
                                                 
                  
                     return cell
                
                    }
        }

     }



 func getXibFile<T: UITableViewCell>(cellType: T.Type, cellIdenifier: String) -> T? {
    return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(cellIdenifier, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? T
 }
```

Comment: Save the entered value, and in `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` put it if there is one saved already..

Comment: persisting them statically i dont think the best option is as it consumes memory

Comment: Saving a String into a var (or an array of string), that should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is creating a new cell every time the tableView reload which is not recommended. You have to `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` so that cell can be reused, which is more efficient in terms of memory.

Regarding data, you might want to have an array to store and retrieve data every time `cellForRow` get called.

Comment: I believe the dequeueReusableCell is for prototype cells and not for Xibs if u read my question properly

Comment: No, reuse is also for xib. I didn't saw that, but clearly, you should reuse (dequeue). That's not your main issue, but that's one issue.